# zmq_ctx_term() blocks while sockets closed

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, zeromq

I am working with ZMQ and am running into issues when destroying a context.

I have the code

```
zmq_ctx_shutdown(context);
zmq_ctx_term(context);
```

This code always blocks on `zmq_ctx_term()` and will also block with `zmq_ctx_destoy()`; however, if that call is removed and only the shutdown call is used, everything seems to work fine, but the application will leak memory from not freeing the zmq context.

In my code, I have four sockets: two `ZMQ_PAIR` `inproc` sockets that are used to communicate between the main thread and a thread with a `ZMQ_REP` socket, along with a `ZMQ_PUB` that runs on the main thread.

I have set `ZMQ_LINGER` on all of these sockets to 0, as it seems the only time the `zmq_ctx_term()` call should block is if messages have not yet been sent since I have called `zmq_close()` on all sockets, which returns without errors. Additionally, this blocking still occurs if I only call `zmq_ctx_new()`, create the sockets, then call `zmq_ctx_shutdown(); zmq_ctx_term();`.

My fear is that something is wrong with using the two `inproc` sockets to communicate between threads with the same zmq context, although there doesn't seem to be any issues with the communication as messages are being received.

After fearing that I may have some issue with thread safety, I found that the ZMQ context should be thread-safe, but not the sockets. I have checked and in the main thread, I am opening an closing the `ZMQ_PUB` socket and `inproc` socket. In another thread, I am opening and closing the `ZMQ_REP` socket and other end of the `inproc` socket, so it seems like that shouldn't be an issue.

For clarification, I am writing my code in C using libzmq from the current master branch on GitHub (commit d35473e). I did see a similar on issues when linking ZMQ's shared library, although this is occurring whether I use the static or shared library. I am currently on OS X 10.9.

If anyone has time to look at the code as a whole, the relevant file is listed [here](http://pastebin.com/SstySqza).

Any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: While the documentation says (on [`zmq_ctx_shutdown`](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-ctx-shutdown)) "This function is optional, client code is still required to call the `zmq_ctx_term` function to free all resources allocated by ZeroMQ.", I'm running into troubles too. I'm currently [not doing](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/blob/master/ZContext.cs#L251) `zmq_ctx_term` if I did `zmq_ctx_shutdown`.

Comment: @metadings I wasn't running into any issues other than a memory leak by not calling `zmq_ctx_term` and in fact thought I was doing the right thing until I read the documentation for `zmq_ctx_shutdown`. It does seem like you shouldn't be setting the context to a null pointer in your `Shutdown` call though since it still needs to be terminated.

Comment: What does the stacktrace looks like when blocked on `zmq_ctx_term()` ?

Comment: @Xaqq The last call I can see regardless of the case are `poll()` and `epoll()` calls, which I would think are coming from a blocking socket, although I am having to send a `SIGINT` to stop execution, so I'm not sure if that is affecting anything. At the moment, zmq debugging symbols are not showing up for me even if I build in debug mode, so I'm trying to figure that out to see what else is going on.

Answer (score 5):

### Observations:

I had the same problem. Despite the fact that I was closing the socket of `ZMQ_REQ` type, and `zmq_close()` returned **`0`**, `zmq_ctx_term()` would still block. This was happening only after sending a message to a peer that was not running.

`zmq_send()` would return immediately, but `zmq_recvmsg()` would time out.

After that I was closing the socket and calling `zmq_ctx_term()`. Apparently, despite the fact that `zmq_close()` returned **`0`**, the sent message was still in an outgoing queue, and for that reason `zmq_ctx_term()` would block.

### Solution:

I solved the problem by setting **`ZMQ_LINGER`** option to half the value of **`ZMQ_RCVTIMEO`**. This behavior is actually described here
http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-ctx-term